# Angular: Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: UserCredential) => UserCredential | PromiseLike<UserCredential>'

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

i try to start a new method, after the registration was successfull. Unfortunately webstorm shows this error:

> Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: UserCredential) => UserCredential | PromiseLike'.

Here is my Code:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    signUp(email: string, password: string) {

        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then(this.goPersonalData());
    }

    login(email: string, password: string) {
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then(success => console.log('its working todo next, goto Main PAge'));
    }

    goPersonalData() {
        this.router.navigate(['/personalData']);
    }
}
```

Its happening in this line:

```
      this.goPersonalData()
```

Comment: `this.goPersonalData()` doesn't return anything, so what do you expect `.then` to do with it? Read the error message, it's telling you what the problem is; `.then` needs a callback that returns `UserCredential` or a promise of one.

Comment: Dominik you can upvote answer as well :)

Comment: sure,  sorry thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify `signup` method as:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

    ...

    signUp(email: string, password: string) {

        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then((res) => {
                this.goPersonalData();
            });
    }

    ...
}
```